# get value of multi input text that have same name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the values of input that have dynamique values and have same name

```
<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validQuantite()" method="post">
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="text" name="qt[]" value=""&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="text" name="qt[]" value=""&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="hidden" name="originqt[]" value="2"&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="hidden" name="originqt[]" value="3"&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<center><input type="Submit" style="WIDTH: 120px; HEIGHT: 25px" name="Confirm" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

javascript

```
function validQuantite() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["qt[]"].values;
    var originqt = document.forms["myForm"]["originqt[]"].values;
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if (x[i] == null || x[i] == "" || x[i] == 0 || x[i] > originqt) {
        alert("error Quantite");
        return false;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First thing check your `html`.
I did not found closing `<` tag for input.

```
<form name="myForm"  method="post"  onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="text" name="qt[]" value=""></b></font></td>
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="text" name="qt[]" value=""></b></font></td>
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="hidden" name="originqt[]" value="2"></b></font></td>
<td align="center"><FONT ><b><input type="hidden" name="originqt[]" value="3"></b></font></td>
<center><input type="Submit" style="WIDTH: 120px; HEIGHT: 25px" name="Confirm" value="Confirm" >
</form>
```

Your javascript should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"].elements.namedItem("qt[]");
    var originqt = document.forms["myForm"].elements.namedItem("originqt[]");
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){

    if (x[i].value == null || x[i].value == "" || x[i].value == 0 || x[i].value > originqt[i].value) {
        alert("error Quantite");
        return false;
    }

    }
}
</script>
```

You have to use `value` with `x[i]`.

Comment: Welcome @SidiMed :)